# Predictive search isn't working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, textbox

This is aspx file code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>AutoComplete Box with jQuery</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tbAuto">Enter UserName: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="autosuggest" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is .cs file code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     public static string getconnectionstring()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crudconnection"].ConnectionString;
    }
    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT username from crudtable where username LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["username"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
            }

    }
}
```

The database "crud" has "crudtable" with columns (username,firstname,lastname,address,id).When i type anything in the textbox and pres button the ,Search isn't working.
Everything seems to be right but don't know where is the error.

Help friends.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in this line of code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
```

Do not add @ in the parameter name.  Use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchText", username);
```

Second add a breakpoint and check if your code is hit by ajax call or not.

Comment: i removed @ but it didn't still work.I added also the break point at 
 $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
But control didn't go there when i entered sometext in box and pressed enter.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Use either network sniffer like fiddler to see if ajax call is made when typing in the text box.You can also use(and is better one) firebug in firefox. Open firebug, Go to Net tab and in sub tab go to XHR and see if it is showing any ajax activity. If it is there then see what is request and what is response.